# how the instances of ThreadPoolExecutor are managed

Tags: java, executorservice

if  multiple requests  executes the instance of ThreadPoolExecutor which has fixed Number of Thread 3
and we use Quad core processor. does each instance of ThreadPoolExecutor maintains its own thread pool or the one thread pool is shared among
instances of ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: each instance of ThreadPoolExecutor maintains its own thread pool

Comment: thanks llya, does it good thing to have to own thread pool of each instance as we left our with only four cores , having singleton ThreadPoolExecutor would be better choice?

Comment: it depends on actual usage, try both, measure and pick one